# How to call a controller method through get request in JSF 1.2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, richfaces, jsf-1.2

The project I'm part of is running JSF 1.2 with RichFaces 3.3. The problem is that in the menu we call the window by a navigation case that renders the page and if I want to call a method in controller I had to use something like `commandButton` or `a4j:jsFunction` using `action` feature (e.g. `#{myController.myMethod}`)  but using request because this is the way that we call it in menu.  I can't use the `onload` of body because it is overwritten by other function. So is there  some way to call the `myMethod` through `get` to make a process in controller before render the page?

Comment: Just do job in bean's constructor or postconstruct? What exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: post construct? how i can access it? i tried in controller contructor, but at this time the DAO is not set yet so i get the nullpointer...

Comment: i tried to use this annotation in a new method in the controller but the project don't start with a error now